# how to return to fragment in android fragmentTabHost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have paint this  problem:

[image]

Do anyone know solution?

Comment: So when navigating from Activity A to Activity B, after `startActivity(intent)` just call `finish()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` using [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 99; // random number here
startActivityForResult(activityAIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

1) In `ActivityB` call:

```
  setResult(RESULT_OK);
  finish();
```

2) In `ActivityA` catch `RESULT_OK` from `ActivityB`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // finish ActivityA and navigate back to FragmentA
           setResult(RESULT_OK);
           finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Other solution** if you don't need `ActivityA` after you start `ActivityB`, then call `finish()` in `ActivityA` where you start `ActivityB`. Having that you can simply call `finish()` in `ActivityB` and user will be navigated back to `FragmentA` as expected.